# How to configure Routes in Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im a newbie to Asp.Net Web Applications. I have created an empty ASP.Net Web Application using MVC in Visual Studio 2017. Im trying to configure Routing in the Web Application. What I have done so far is adding an "App_Start" Folder to the Project & then creating a class file called RouteConfig.cs with following Code:

RouteConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebApplicationBS_Web.
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
          {
            routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapPageRoute(
                routeName: "Login",
                routeUrl: "Login",
                physicalFile: "~/Default.aspx"
                );
        }

    }
}
```

I have then edited the Global.asax file as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebApplicationBS_Web.App_Start
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to now configure routing in web.config in such a way that the Url at the Browser shud appear as http://localhost:58170/Login

I have already build the Website & viewed it in Visual Studio IIS Express but it seems to load the Default.aspx with no Url Routing.

the Web.Config File so far is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7"/>
  </system.web>
  <location>
    <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument>
        <files>
          <clear/>
          <add value="Default.aspx"/>
        </files>
      </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

How do i go about this ??

Comment: I am wondering if you have the idea of routing backwards in your head. It sounds like you are expecting the URL to show up as http://localhost:58170/Login when going to the default site?, but your routing as is just means that when you go to that URL the default site will be shown. Bottom line, it would be helpful to know what URL you are going to and what you are expecting to see.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) module. Then you can set this up like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rule name="login" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
        <match url="*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/Login*" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/default.aspx" />
      </rule>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
<configuration>
```

Comment: I have reconfigured web.config with above code but it seems to give an error                                                                                                      
"HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server."

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Login",
            url: "Login",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "LoginIndex" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

You can use this scheme

First route goes to http://yoururl/Login

Second is the default you can use as Home/Index.

Home is controller name ındex is the action

Comment: I have made an edit in the Post, the Project is for MVC but its an empty project.

Comment: ok. so I need to create a folder called Login & then adding Index.aspx

Comment: First you should create a folder named controllers . Then add a controller in it

Comment: You should first create controllers folder and view folder so you can add controller class.

You can find detailed information here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller

Comment: ok.. but mvc only successfully loads .cshtml files & not login.aspx files

Comment: As far as i know aspx files are outdated at mvc. You should create a Login View or Login Partial view. Maybe you should try to follow this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset